# Connections to SQL Server not closing under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

We have a problem with a webserver (ASP.NET, C# + Silverlight) application running under IIS that where we reach the max limit of SQL Server connections and get errors.

Yes - we have checked that we are closing each connection and disposing it correctly.

It works very well in Visual Studio and the build in 'light IIS-web server'. There we do not get the error. But when we put the same code under a real Win2008R2 IIS, (or on a development laptop running Win8.1 IIS), then we can reproduce the error over and over again.

Anyone having some ideas?

What is the difference between the built in 'light IIS-web server' in VS and a real IIS that might cause this kind of behaviour?

/Erik

Comment: When does it reach the limit (on both tests) - re: how many users/requests? Before getting into details, maybe show some of the code where you _think_ connections are closed/disposed might help track the issue down - as it is, all you're going to get will be guesses..Unsure what you're referring to as "light" - VS dev or IIS Express? Either way, # of users/requests (in conjunction with OS) is one difference (there are more).

Comment: Show code that demonstrates the pattern you use to close connections.

Comment: There shouldn't be any appreciable difference between the IIS installations, and odds are that error is coming from SQL, not IIS.  Please show the code.  Are you using one SQL server account for all of your data access, or do you have different accounts you're using?  (Such as each user having a different login?)

Comment: After 4 days of searching... yes it was a connection leak. Very hard to find due to the level of abstraction.